# Domain Name System Record A database

Tags: data-request, internet

Searching for a [IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) to [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) database lookup that is from an source that provides updates & archives. Possible this might require a number of sources, since I'm looking for [all TLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains).

Comment: See answer to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/dataset-of-domain-names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [DNS Census 2013](http://dnscensus2013.neocities.org/) is an attempt to provide a public dataset of registered domains and DNS records.

The torrent is about 15 GB (uncompressed: 157 GB).

I am pretty sure it contains domain names and IPs, but I am not 100% sure as I have not downloaded it to check. Please let us know, thanks!

You can extract TLD from domain name.

Comment: I downloaded it and it does have domains and IPs: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/dataset-of-domain-names/21077#21077