# List of all http sites in the world

Tags: data-request, internet

I've tried inurl:http but it takes forever to get even a bunch of sites right and I have to think of new keywords everytime to get the sites.

Is there kind of a directory I could use to get the address of all the sites on the public web?

Comment: Also HTTPS I guess?

Comment: what is inurl:http

Comment: you probably do **not** want to run this:  `curl -IL http://{0..255}.{0..255}.{0..255}.{0..255}` 

Comment: I think `inurl:http` is an attempted hack on google advance searching: https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/, but I'm pretty sure google doesn't consider the application protocol to be meaningful when indexing the sites.

Comment: http://commoncrawl.org/ would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

There are an estimated [1.6 billion public websites](https://www.internetlivestats.com/total-number-of-websites/) in the world, with 200 million being active. But no one really knows, because a website can be just an IP address with no domain, or an [.onion link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion), or temporary or short-lived, or [weather-dependent](https://solar.lowtechmagazine.com/), ...

---

One way would be to use known DNS records (domain names) from the **[2013 DNS Census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/2122/1511)**.

> It is a DNS registration dataset snapshot taken in 2013. Compressed - it is ~15GB and uncompressed 157GB.
>
> They claim it contains: Dataset containing 2,676,380,336 DNS records and 106,928,034 domains

---

A more modest list would be, for example, the [Alexa 1 million list](https://github.com/mozilla/cipherscan/tree/master/top1m):

> Scripts for scanning the Alexa top 1 million sites and providing generic
> statistics about them.

Direct link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip

---

Or, like [my comment](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15368/list-of-all-http-sites-in-the-world#comment18283_15368), [loop over IPv4 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47076164/2327328)... and record if each IP is a valid http/https server.

[Here's an estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437185/2327328) about how big your `for loop` will get:

> According to [Reserved IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) there are 588,514,304 reserved addresses and since there are 4,294,967,296 (2^32) IPv4 addressess in total, there are **3,706,452,992** public addresses.

Comment: Does your number include port numbers

Comment: @nmtoken nope! but if you have more cycles you can always add all the ports that aren't usually associated with http(s) to see if http(s) is running there ;)